# Default parameters in template functions (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, default

I'm trying to use default parameters in a template function. The following is a minimal example of the thing I'm trying to do:

#### In **sort.h**

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void sort(Vector<T0> &v0,Vector<T1> &v1=0)
{
    //sort v0, if (v1 != 0) sort it according to v0
}
```

#### In **main.cpp**

```
#include "sort.h"
Vector<int> v0;
sort(v0);
```

This does not compile; the compiler gives the error "no matching function to call to 'sort'".

Basically this function should sort the vector v0 (arbitrary datatype). In addition, a second vector v1 (arbitrary) which is sorted in the same way as vector v0 can be given as parameter. Of course I could solve this problem simply by using overloaded functions, but since I'd like to expand the list of additional vectors up to 5, I would need like hundreds of different functions.

**Update:** Thanks for your responses so far. I have modified my problem description to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: std::sort is of no use since it sorts only one single vector. but i want sort one vector and rearrange multiple others in the same way.

Answer (score 8):

A reference can't point at nothing.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot default a reference to 0.  You'd have to use pointers to do this (if you insist).

There's also no way for the compiler to intuit what `T1` is without an actual `Vector<X>` to work from.  A concrete parameter type would be needed for parameter 2.  If the second parameter was `Vector<T0>*`, for example, that would be OK since the type can be divined from parameter 1 (which is not defaulted).  Otherwise, you'll have to specify the template parameters on every call to `testfunction`.

Adding info on what you are trying to achieve might enable better answers to be provided.  This seems a little convoluted.

Comment: @wilhelmtell - don't you mean your crossbow?

Answer (score 2):

I would just simply overload the function.

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void sort(Vector<T0> &v0,Vector<T1> &v1)
{
    //do something
}
void sort(Vector<T0> &v0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You forgot `template<class T0>` before second sort.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void testfunction(Vector<T0> &v0,const Vector<T1> &v1 = Vector<T1>() )
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: but you'd have to instantiate the function then.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're giving a default value for the second argument in testfunction, the compiler has no way of deriving T1 if you don't give it something to go on.  You need to explicitly state the type.  Something like:

```
testfuntion<int, float>(v0);
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you need to find some way of properly declaring the second argument since a reference can't have "null" value.  I personally like [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400939/default-parameters-in-template-functions-c/4400969#4400969).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change it to use pointers instead:

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void testfunction(Vector<T0>* v0, Vector<T1>* v1 = 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Right - if you are going to start using pointers, why not just go all out?

Comment: Pretty much.  If you pass in the first vector by reference and the second by pointer (you're essentially passing pointers to both anyway), so make the syntax consistent.

Comment: @ZacHowland references and pointers are two very different beasts. Also: what @SteveTownsend is trying to hint (if I understand correctly) is that you're taking "consistency" waay out of context here. If I'm getting Steve wrong then I'll sign my own name under that.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  You're taking it too literally.  A reference is (essentially) a pointer that has a couple extra guarantees.  That is, what gets passed to your function is a memory address not an object.  That is what I was getting at (not that pointers and references are identical).  Since you passed in both by non-const reference, I'm assuming you are planning to manipulate their data in some way, so having one passed in as `vector<T0>&` and the other as `vector<T1>*` would force code to look like `v0.push_back((*v1)[3])` or conversely `v1->push_back(v0[3])`.  Its just a preference.